# Replace all occurrences matching regular expression in the first word of a line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to parse an ASCII file and escape "." characters in the first word of each line. Here is an example:

```
line='DXa0.Xa1.a2 p1 p2 deviceName  a=157.585p b=54.46u $x=106.124 $y=107.996 $a=0'
```

I would like to produce the following

```
DXa0\.Xa1\.a2 p1 p2 deviceName  a=157.585p b=54.46u $x=106.124 $y=107.996 $a=0
```

I could run the following for this example:

```
re.sub(r"\.", '\\.', line, count=2 )
```

But that assumes 2 "." characters in the word, which is not guaranteed. The workaround I found for now is

```
re.sub(r"\.", '\\.', line.split(' ', 1)[0]) + ' ' + line.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

It produces the expected results but that's not pretty, I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve that with `re` using a regex to match the first word up to the first whitespace after the first streak of non-whitespace chars and a lambda expression as the replacement argument:

```
re.sub(r"^\s*\S+", lambda x: x.group().replace('.', r'\.'), s)
```

Here, `^\s*\S+` matches any 0+ whitespaces and then 1+ non-whitespaces at the start of the string, and then all `.` in that match (`x.group()`) are replaced with `\.` char sequences.

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/FWUUT43712).

If you install the [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you will be able to achieve what you need with a single `regex.sub` call:

```
import regex
s = 'DXa0.Xa1.a2 p1 p2 deviceName  a=157.585p b=54.46u $x=106.124 $y=107.996 $a=0'
rx = r'\G[^\s.]*\K\.'
print(regex.sub(rx, r'\\.', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/AGDJ15542). Also, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/64teGb/1).

**Details**

- `\G` - start of a string or the end of the previous successful match
- `[^\s.]*` - 0 or more chars other than a whitespace (`\s`) and a dot (a dot inside square brackets only matches a `.` char)
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far in the current iteration
- `\.` - a dot.

You may do without a `\K` if you use capturing/backreference:

```
regex.sub(r'\G([^\s.]*)\.', r'\1\\.', s)
```

Comment: Is the `regexp` module really necessary? (According to the [Python code generator](https://regex101.com/r/64teGb/1/codegen?language=python) available from your exemple URL, the regular expression you propose seems to work with just `re`...)

Comment: @ErikMD If it were not necessary, I would not have mentioned that. Do not trust regex101.com. It will "generate" the code from this regex [even for JS](https://regex101.com/r/64teGb/1/codegen?language=javascript) that has never had any support for such specific operators as `\G` and `\K`.

Comment: Indeed: I now realize that the warning footer in the code generator page is not expendable :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you *have to* stick with `re`?

Without it's easy:

```
p = line.partition(' ')

escaped = p[0].replace(r'.', r'\.') + p[1] + p[2]

escaped
Out:
'DXa0\\.Xa1\\.a2 p1 p2 deviceName  a=157.585p b=54.46u $x=106.124 $y=107.996 $a=0'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could find the first *word* and replace the `.` in there, for instance:

```
import re

line = 'DXa0.Xa1.a2.b3.b4 p1 p2 deviceName  a=157.585p b=54.46u $x=106.124 $y=107.996 $a=0'

def repl(m):
    return m.group().replace(".", "\\.")

print(re.sub(r"^\S+", repl, line.lstrip()))
```

**Output**

```
DXa0\.Xa1\.a2\.b3\.b4 p1 p2 deviceName  a=157.585p b=54.46u $x=106.124 $y=107.996 $a=0
```

Comment: The regex may look even simpler then, `r"^\S+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated the answer.